How to describe a village’s expanding owing to its people building more houses southwards?
I'm learning to describe the changes in a map and would like to know diverse ways to describe this.
What should I write here?


The village grew southwards.
The village expanded southwards.
The population of the village grew southwards.
The population of the village expanded southwards.


I'm also unsure whether southwards is okay here. Maybe to the south?
If there are better sentences that you have in mind, I'd love to hear them! Thank you!

Or simply "expanded south".

4 sounds like the people of the village grew larger in a southerly direction.

Both 1 and 2 are correct.
"Grow" and "expand" mean the same thing here.
3 and 4 are acceptable but weird. You are presumably talking about the physical size of the village, not its population, even if the population increases as that happens.
"Southwards" and "southward" and "to the south" all mean the same thing in this context and can be used interchangeably.

+1, and the reason 3 and 4 don’t work is that when population and the verb grow (or the noun growth) appear together, that almost requires that population have the sense of “number of residents,” rather than the sense of “aggregate (set) of all the residents.” This latter sense could be expressed by replacing population with populace. But even if we did that replacement, grew would be far less natural than spread or expanded.

My first thought here was southwards is unlikely compared to to the south. And here's the chart to prove it.

I think "southwards" has slightly more of a sense of incremental growth while "to the south" could mean a one-time thing (e.g. they built a new estate/project to the south). But it's not a clear-cut difference.
